# Wald lemma for Brownian motion

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

In the following question, $B$ refers to Brownian motion.

I am having a problem with a particular part of the solution of the following question (picture below). More precisely, how to prove that $$M(4^{p+1})-M(4^p) \leq |B_{4^{p+1}}-B_{4^p}|?$$

[Picture:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNfrX.png)

> We wish to show that when $T$ is a stopping time with $\mathbb{E}\left[T^{1 / 2}\right]<\infty$, Wald's lemma still applies and $\mathbb{E}\left[B_{T}\right]=0$
>
> (1) Define $\tau:=\min \left\{k: 4^{k} \geq T\right\}$. Set $M(t):=\max _{[0, t]} B$ and $X_{k}:=M\left(4^{k}\right)-2^{k+2}$. Show that $\left(X_{k}\right)$ is a supermartingale for the filtration $\left(\mathcal{F}_{4^{k}}\right)_{k}$, and that $\tau$ is a stopping time.
>
> **Solution** (1) Define $\tau:=\min \left\{k: 4^{k} \geq T\right\}$. Set $M(t):=\max _{[0, t]} B$ and
> $$
> \mathbb{E}\left[X_{k+1}-X_{k} \mid \mathcal{F}_{4^{k}}\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[M\left(4^{k+1}\right)-M\left(4^{k}\right) \mid \mathcal{F}_{4^{k}}\right]-4 \times 2^{k}
> $$
> Since we know that almost surely $M\left(4^{k+1}\right)-M\left(4^{k}\right) \leq\left|B_{4^{k+1}}-B_{4^{k}}\right|$ which is independent of $\mathcal{F}_{4^{k}}$ and distributed like $\left|B_{4^{k+1}-4^{k}}\right|$, then
> $$
> \mathbb{E}\left[X_{k+1}-X_{k} \mid \mathcal{F}_{4^{k}}\right] \leq \mathbb{E}\left[\left|B_{4^{k+1}-4^{k}}\right|\right]-4 \times 2^{k}=\sqrt{3 \times 4^{k}} \mathbb{E}\left[\left|B_{1}\right|\right]-4 \times 2^{k}
> $$
> A simple application of Cauchy-Schwarz or Jensen gives $\mathbb{E}\left[\left|B_{1}\right|\right] \leq \sqrt{\mathbb{E}\left[\left|B_{1}\right|^{2}\right]}=1$, and the expectation above is bounded by 0 .

Comment: What is $M$ here?

Comment: It is defined in the question (the desired inequality is mentioned without a proof)

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain the reason of downvoting? It would be logical to downvote if it was a question without providing an attempt, which isn't the case, because here I asked a very specific question on the solution (one of many other solutions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3604966/wald-s-identity-for-brownian-motion-with-e-sqrt-t-infty?noredirect=1&lq=1) that I found on the internet and where a detail was omitted.

Comment: To fix this (it might be overkill in your context) but BDG inequalities might do the trick (or maybe Doob if you can square at some point the sup of B ). You might prove something like : $$E[M(4^{k+1})]\leq C_1. E[<B(4^{k+1})>^{1/2}] = C_1E[(4^{k+1})^{1/2}]=C_1.2^{k+1} $$ so by substracting $M(4^{k})$ and $4.2^{k}$ all this adds up to some negative number (at least for some $k$ big enough to forget about $C_1$).

Comment: By the way here is a reference for BDG inequalities : https://almostsuremath.com/2010/04/06/the-burkholder-davis-gundy-inequality/

Comment: @TheBridge another proof that doesn't relies on BDG is available in the following book (available also online): https://www.amazon.com/Brownian-Cambridge-Statistical-Probabilistic-Mathematics/dp/0521760186/ref=sr_1_1?crid=31WE3ZUSMROXY&keywords=brownian+motion&qid=1648594715&sprefix=brownian+motion%2Caps%2C138&sr=8-1

Comment: Also the reflection principle used in the proof given in the book could be avoided by noting that $E[\sup_{r \in [0,1]}B_r] \leq (E[(\sup_{r \in [0,1]}B_r)^2])^{\frac{1}{2}} \leq 2(E[B_1^2])^{\frac{1}{2}} \leq 2$ (Doob inquality)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof seems wrong take the event where $B_{4^{p+1}}=B_{4^p}=M(4^p)=2$, and $M(4^{p+1})=4$ then $2=M(4^{p+1})-M(4^p) \not\leq |B_{4^{p+1}}-B_{4^p}|=0$

This event has null proba but you can take intervals of non null proba instead and obtain the claim wrong.
For example take the event where, $B_{4^p}\in (1,2)$, $|B_{4^{p+1}}-B_{4^p}|< 1/2$,   $|M_{4^{p}}-B_{4^p}|\leq 1$ and $M(4^{p+1}) \in (9,10)$ then
$M(4^{p+1})-M(4^p)>9 -(2+1) =6$ and $|B_{4^{p+1}}-B_{4^p}|\leq 1/2$

All those events combined have non null probability (even though I really don't want to calculate this)

So we don't have almost surely :

$$M(4^{p+1})-M(4^p) \leq |B_{4^{p+1}}-B_{4^p}|$$